# Function with variable arguments as parameter to another function

Tags: c#

How can I define a function that expects another function that returns a bool in c#?

To clarify, this is what I'd like to do using C++:

```
void Execute(boost::function<int(void)> fctn)
{
    if(fctn() != 0)
    {
        show_error();
    }
}

int doSomething(int);
int doSomethingElse(int, string);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Execute(boost::bind(&doSomething, 12));
    Execute(boost::bind(&doSomethingElse, 12, "Hello"));
}
```

In my example above the `Execute` function in combination is with the `bind` gets the expected result.

Background:

I've got a bunch of functions, each returning a int but with different parameter count that are surrounded by the same error checking code. A huge code duplication I want to avoid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want by using [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example

```
void Execute(Func<bool> myFunc)
{
   if(myFunc() == false)
   {
      // Show error
   }
}
```

You can then define your Func either as a method, or a lambda:

```
// Define a method
private bool MethodFunc() {}

// Pass in the method
Execute(MethodFunc)

// Pass in the Lambda
Execute(() => { return true; });
```

You don't nececssairly need to pass the parameters in as you can now access them from the caller's scope:

```
Execute(() => { return myBool; });
Execute(() => { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr); });
```

Comment: A `Func<bool>` is a function that returns bool without parameters, i.e. the same as a C++ `Func<bool(void)>` ?

Comment: But you can now access them via the calling lambda - so you don't explicitly need to define them on the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

With my solution, you can perform any function, any input parameter, with any return, this is a very generic implementation

**Example:**

```
public T YourMethod<T>(Func<T> functionParam)
{
   return functionParam.Invoke();
}

public bool YourFunction(string foo, string bar, int intTest)
{
    return true;
}
```

**Call like This specifying the return :**

```
YourMethod<bool>(() => YourFunction("bar", "foo", 1));
```

**Or like this:**

```
YourMethod(() => YourFunction("bar", "foo", 1));
```

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke` to call the function, instead of calling it directly?

Comment: its more easy if you need to pass parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
  without argument  do this 

  void Execute(Func<bool> fctn)
    {
        if(fctn() )
        {
            show_error();
        }
    }  

  with arguments you can do something like this:

    void Execute<T>(Func<T[],bool> fctn)
    {
        var v = new T[4];
        if(fctn(v) )
        {
            show_error();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I use that with a function that has parameters (the bind part)?